# How to add callbacks for multiple graphs in a Dash/Plotly app automatically

Tags: python, dashboard, python-decorators, plotly-dash

In a single-page [Dash by Plotly](https://dash.plot.ly/) app I want to show many similar graphs.

For this I have created a "factory class" which can generate many graphs.

This class exposes methods to be used in the Dash app's `app.layout` and `@app.callback` code. A sample `app.py` with two graphs looks like this:

```
import ...

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

graph_A = GraphFactory(feature="A")
graph_B = GraphFactory(feature="B")

app.layout = html.Div([
            graph_A.graph(),
            graph_B.graph(),
            ])

@app.callback(
    graph_A.callback_output(), graph_A.callback_inputs()
)
def update_A(value):
    return graph_A.callback_update(value)

@app.callback(
    graph_B.callback_output(), graph_B.callback_inputs()
)
def update_B(value):
    return graph_B.callback_update(value)
```

This works fine. However I want to display many graphs from a list of `GraphFactory` objects. It's easy to create the objects and put them in the app layout:

```
graph_list = [ GraphFactory(feature=f) for f in feature_list ]

app.layout = html.Div([ 
            g.graph() for g in graph_list
            ])
```

But **how can I add the many `callback_output()`, `callback_inputs()` and `callback_update(value)` calls? Is there a way to write the decorator and the function only once and add the calls to the `callback_...` functions in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By digging into decorators I found a solution myself: You can call the Dash decorator on the object's `callback_update` function directly. So for the example from the question you can write:

```
for g in graph_list:
    dash_app.callback(g.callback_output(),
                      g.callback_inputs())(g.callback_update)
```

Please note carefully, that `g.callback_update` has no `()`, because the `app.callback` function is applied to the `g.callback_update` *function/method*, not as usual to its *return value*.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else looks for another way of doing this, a solution was introduced in Dash 0.39 - Multiple Outputs.

https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437

> Use a list/tuple of Output as output in callbacks.
> Return a tuple/list of value from the callbacks
> The returned list must have the same length as the list of output
> The output props are applied in the order they were declared in the output > list.

'Applied' = outputs declared in callback applied in app.layout in order from top to bottom